# Dynamic growth of `Actor`s vs Primal creation

Tags: scala, akka

In my project, I have defined groups of `Actor`s called *cells*. Those cells process `message`s and operate basic calculations of some different kinds, one kind by small `Actor` type.

What is the advantage(s) of growing those small `Actor`s, then killing them once the job is done, rather than creating them on my cell initialization, roaming till `system` shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll crate one actor per job, you'll get parallel processing of messages, while if you'll create actor on initialization, you messages of the same type will be processed one by one.
Usually, you shouldn't use actors for parallel execution of your programm, their task is to process common resources, like incrementing counters in multi threaded programm. If you want parallel processing of messages, use [futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)